# Customized Page on SharePoint Enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, design, homepage

I have a new requirement from my manager to create a new customized home page for one of our team. The design includes a lot of requirements to be fulfilled but i cannot start with the design as i want to edit the page according to my needs using html but also want sharePoint technology to be used in this.
For example : I have a image carousel to be used in the home page but i am unable to design it according to my needs.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started.

- Upload your JavaScript and CSS files to the Site Assets folder of the site.
- Create a .txt file with the links to those files, just like you would link to them in the header in a standard HTML file and place this also in the Site Assets folder of the site.

eg.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="yourlocation.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourlocation.js"></script>
```

- Edit the new home page, add a content editor web part (From the Ribbon: Insert > Web Part > Media and Content > Content Editor > Add). Once added (and still in edit mode) click the upper left Edit Control Block (down arrow) on the web part and click Edit Web Part.
- In the web part preferences under "Content Link" paste the URL to your .txt file, then Apply. Save the page.

Any JavaScript or CSS from your files you added in Site Assets will now apply to the page.

If you need to add a div on the page, like a container div for the image carousel, edit the page, click inside the text portion of the Content Editor Web Part and click "Edit Source" from the ribbon. Add your container div and save the page.